# getCatalogItem: Access to requested resource is denied

Tags: postman, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to call **getCatalogItem** in Postman but getting

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "details": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting the following when sending a marketplaceParticipations request to `sellers/v1/marketplaceParticipations` via Postman after following instructions and examples provided at https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/connecting-to-the-selling-partner-api

```
{
    "payload": [
        {
            "marketplace": {
                "id": "AHRY1CZE9ZY4H",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "name": "Amazon.com Invoicing Shadow Marketplace",
                "defaultCurrencyCode": "USD",
                "defaultLanguageCode": "en_US",
                "domainName": "invoicing-shadow-marketplace.amazon.com"
            },
            "participation": {
                "isParticipating": true,
                "hasSuspendedListings": false
            }
        },
        {
            "marketplace": {
                "id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "name": "Amazon.com",
                "defaultCurrencyCode": "USD",
                "defaultLanguageCode": "en_US",
                "domainName": "www.amazon.com"
            },
            "participation": {
                "isParticipating": true,
                "hasSuspendedListings": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but when I am trying to call any other API endpoint I am getting `Access to requested resource is denied.` [The Response and API Call in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUVIf.png)
[access key as x-amz-access-token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKx8T.png) [aws auth signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAftA.png)

I am calling https://api.amazon.com/auth/O2/token to get access key [Here the postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEsok.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the required permissions for making that call. The [documentation](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/catalog-items-api-v2022-04-01-use-case-guide) says you need

> Approval for the Product Listing role in your developer profile.

and

> The Product Listing role selected in the App registration page for your application.